# Sincronização automatica de base de dados no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, tenho uma base de dados MySQL local onde a disponibilidade é  de 24h, no entanto possuo outra base de dados em outro local que fica disponível por algumas horas, enfim... Eu quero sincronizar duas bases de dados idênticas automaticamente quando ambas estiverem disponíveis, com o detalhe de que alterações são efetuadas nas duas bases de dados! Existe algum método que faça isto?

Comment: *com o detalhe de que alterações são efetuadas nas duas bases de dados!* Então você utilizou o termo **replicação** de forma equivocada.

Comment: Entendo, vou alterar!

Comment: Você quer que seja feito uma cópia do seu banco de dados oficial? É isso? ou você quer sincronizar dois bancos, pegar dados de um para o outro?

Comment: Quero pegar dados de um para o outro, de forma que os dois fiquem idênticos. Se atualizar um, o outro também atualizar e vice versa. Levando em consideração que um deles não estará 24h disponivel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer é uma replicação de dados MASTER-MASTER.

Tem um passo-a-passo no link http://blog.websolute.com.br/como-configurar-replicacao-multi-master-para-mysql-no-jelastic/

O processo é até simples mas requer atenção ao definir o offset do autoincrement.

Comment: Link offline =(